# Curly Bracket Default Layout in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When creating conditional statements, or mthods, the IDE jumps to this:

```
      if (true)
      {
       //code here      
      }
```

But I'd prefer the following more compact style (and often used in text books)

```
      if (true) {
       //code here      
      }
```

Is there a setting in visual studio to change the default style?

Comment: I wanted the reverse. This question, helped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go `Tools` > `Options` in the top menu bar.

In the left panel, go to `Text Editor` > `C#` > `Code Style` > `Formatting` > `New Lines`.

The option for `if` blocks is `Place open brace on new line for control blocks`, but you may want to change it for other types of block too. You may also want to change `Place "else" on new line`.

Comment: this is excellent - this IDE is quite some piece of work - MS have really put a lot into it ...

Comment: seems to be called `Place open brace on new line for control blacks` in VS 2010 ...I'm unchecking them all!

Answer (score 3):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > New Lines > Place open brace on new line...